# Matlab with 2 icons on the dock in linux Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation, icons, launcher, matlab

I installed MATLAB R2021A and I found that when creating the `matlab.desktop` it generated problems, and it was that two icons appeared in the dock, I put MATLAB in favorites but when I opened it, it did not open from there, if not it opened in another.

[image]

Comment: Sebastian, glad you solved it, and welcome to AskUbuntu. As a next step, you should copy-and paste your solution into the Answer section below. Then Edit your question, remove the word "[Solved]" from the title, and remove the solution portion of text. In a few days, you will be able to come back check-mark your own Answer as accepted. This way, you will help others having the same issue to easily find a working solution.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I managed to solve it, in many places I saw that I had to add this `StartupWMClass = com-mathworks-util-PostVMInit` in `/usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop` but it did not help me, finally what I did was add that line but different

```
StartupWMClass=MATLAB R2021a - academic use
```

take the value from what appears at the top when opening MATLAB

[image]

but one thing was missing to select the correct image of the icon, since generally one finds that they download it from the internet, but this generates an error, so it is better to choose the one that comes in the download files, since it seems that two icons appear because there are errors in the `matlab.desktop` that makes it impossible to open from there

```
Icon=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2021A/bin/glnxa64/cef_resources/matlab_icon.png
```

Finally I leave the complete `matlab.desktop` file

```
    #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
    [Desktop Entry]
    Type=Application
    Icon=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2021A/bin/glnxa64/cef_resources/matlab_icon.png   
    Name=MATLAB R2021a
    Comment=Start MATLAB - The Language of Technical Computing
    #Uncomment the following line and comment the line after to   
    #force matlab to use the 32 bits architecture
    #Exec=matlab -arch=glnx86 -desktop
    Exec=matlab -desktop
    Terminal=false
    Categories=Development;
    StartupNotify=true
    #Uncomment the following line if you've got several matlab icons in the launcher
    StartupWMClass=MATLAB R2021a - academic use
```

[image]

Comment: `StartupWMClass=MATLAB` may be enough - I don't think a WMClass can have spaces.

Comment: Probe only with MATLAB and I keep getting two icons, it only works for me completely

Answer (score 0):

**Guaranteed solution:**

In order for icons to appear correctly, StartupWMClass needs to be set in the desktop entry **correctly**.

Step by step:

1. Run the command below if you haven't already

```
sudo apt install matlab-support
```

2. Open the matlab.desktop file with an editor. We will add a new line to this file after Step 5.

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop
```

3. Launch MATLAB by running `matlab`.
4. Then, while keeping the window open, open the terminal again and type the command below, then click on the MATLAB window.

```
xprop | grep WM_CLASS
```

5. Copy the result. It might be something like:

```
sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer
```

6. Then add/update the following line at the end of the `matlab.desktop` file we opened in Step 3.

```
StartupWMClass=**RESULT OBTAINED IN STEP 5**
```